# How to solve "Vulkan Error" and "Running multiple Emulator with the same AVD Error" in the Android studio?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

Whenever I try to select a device from the "Flutter device selection" this message pops up:

> Error Opening Emulator
> INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.205.217

Here's a image of that message:[Error message that pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlz2x.png)

I tried to open an emulator for Android project but when I went on selecting the AVD I got an error message.